# Having some trouble forming a proper SQL query using NOT IN and PHP array

Tags: php, sql

ok, I'm not too schooled on SQL yet and what I want to do is, I have an array of search engine bots and IP's (or partial IP's) that I want to exclude from being returned in the SQL results.

The array is already properly formed for the SQL query and looks like this (and is stored in $sql_exclude):

```
'googlebot', 'crawl', 'spider', 'bluehost', 'amazonaws', 'msnbot', 'surphace-scout', 'scoutjet', 'facebook', 'tfbnw.net', 'digg', 'spinn3r', 'favsys.net', 'trendnet.org', '72.14.192.', '72.14.194.'
```

The query checks against both the ip and user_agent columns in the db, to see if either of those contain any of the items in the array, and if so, I don't want them returned in the results.

Right now, this is the query I have tried and makes the most "sense" to me, but it's not returning anything at all. Can anyone point out where the error is?

```
$sql = "SELECT w.* FROM {bad_behavior_log} w WHERE ($sql_exclude) NOT IN w.user_agent AND ($sql_exclude) NOT IN w.ip " . tablesort_sql($header);
```

Also, since user agents are mixed case, is that an issue? And/or when a user agent it's checking against has the word "GoogleBot" in it and the array term is just "google", will the SQL query automatically find the partial match? (for the partial IP's as well).

**Update:**
For the sake of thoroughness, and in case anyone reads this later, I solved my issue with 2 things:

1) For some reason, not sure if it's my Host's setup (Bluehost), I needed to convert all search strings for my comparison operators (NOT LIKE) into uppercase, or it would arbitrarily match some and not match some mixed case searches.

2) The parenthesis around my SQL variables were also causing the query to choke. i.e. ($sql_exclude) should've been just $sql_exclude.

Here's my final, working, query string:
    $sql = "SELECT w.* FROM {bad_behavior_log} w WHERE w.user_agent NOT LIKE $sql_exclude_agents AND w.ip NOT LIKE $sql_exclude_ips" . tablesort_sql($header);

and the strings in those variables look like this:
    $sql_exclude_agents = "'%".implode("%' AND w.user_agent NOT LIKE '%", $exclude_agents)."%'";

(turns into)
    NOT LIKE '%GOOGLE%' AND w.user_agent NOT LIKE '%YAHOOCACHESYSTEM%' AND w.user_agent NOT LIKE '%RSSGRAFFITI%' AND w.user_agent NOT LIKE '%BITLYBOT%' (etc.)

Comment: `NOT IN` will not get a partial match

Answer (score 3):

You are using NOT IN incorrectly, the format should be `column NOT IN ($sql_exclude)` as opposed to the reverse. I.e. it should be followed by the list of items to check instead of being proceeded by it.

`$sql = "SELECT w.* FROM {bad_behavior_log} w WHERE w.user_agent NOT IN ($sql_exclude) AND w.ip NOT IN ($sql_exclude) " . tablesort_sql($header)`

Comment: Seems all replies so far are mentioning the same placement thing so i'm just replying to the person who first answered, but this is still addressed to all: I originally did have it that way and it did return results, however, I guess then is where I'm running into the partial matching issue, because it was still returning matches that contained the user agents that I didnt' want returned. What is the right way to do what I need including partial matches?

Comment: Yes, this is correct it is likely the issue with partial matching. NOT IN lists do direct matching so will only return direct matches. As such, you could use a combination of NOT IN for your direct matches, coupled with a LIKE clause for the more general. For example: `WHERE w.user_agent NOT IN ($sql_exclude) && w.ip NOT IN ($sql_exclude) && w.user_agent NOT LIKE '%google%'` for a more generic exclusion against google. You could also instead attempt to conform all your strings to direct matches if that is easier.

Comment: Alright, so I've given up on NOT IN and am trying NOT LIKE. Still having trouble. The new $sql_exclude string looks like: `'%googlebot%' OR '%crawl%' OR '%spider%' OR '%bluehost%' OR '%amazonaws%' OR '%msnbot%' OR '%surphace-scout%' OR '%scoutjet%'` And the query looks like: `$sql = "SELECT w.* FROM {bad_behavior_log} w WHERE w.user_agent NOT LIKE ($sql_exclude) AND w.ip NOT LIKE ($sql_exclude) " . tablesort_sql($header);` It's still returning results that contain the matches I don't want? @paulbailey

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to swap your `NOT IN` clauses around. it should be `column_name NOT IN (list_of_values)`.

Case sensitivity depends on how your database is configured.

The query won't do partial matches, only exact ones (case issues aside). To do partial matches in SQL, you'll need to use `LIKE` and the `%` wildcard. That doesn't work in an `IN`/`NOT IN` list either.

Answer (score 1):

```
   $sql = "SELECT w.* FROM {bad_behavior_log} w 
WHERE w.user_agent NOT IN ($sql_exclude) AND w.ip NOT IN ($sql_exclude) " . tablesort_sql($header);
```